# How to extract elements from a String with jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to write a small piece of code that will exctract the "Kategorie" out of a href with jsoup.

```
<a href="/wiki/Kategorie:Herrscher_des_Mittelalters" title="Kategorie:Herrscher des Mittelalters">Herrscher des Mittelalters</a>
```

In this case I am searching for `Herrscher des Mittelalters`.

My code reads the first line of a .txt file with the `BufferedReader`.

```
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath)), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(r.readLine());
    Element elem = doc;
```

I know there are commands to get the href-link but I don't know commands to search for elements in the href-link.

Any suggestions?

Additional information: My .txt file contains full Wikipedia HTML pages.

Comment: does <a> contain any id ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont know much about HTML. What do you mean by id?

Comment: no probs, look at my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you all titles from links. You can split the titles further as you need:

```
    Document d = Jsoup.parse("<a href=\"/wiki/Kategorie:Herrscher_des_Mittelalters\" title=\"Kategorie:Herrscher des Mittelalters\">Herrscher des Mittelalters</a>");

    Elements links = d.select("a");

    Set<String> categories = new HashSet<>();
    for (Element script : links) {
        String title = script.attr("title");
        if (title.length() > 0) {
            categories.add(title);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsContainingText() method (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) to search for elements with with any text.

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsContainingText("Herrscher des Mittelalters");
   for(int i=0; i<elements.size();i++) {
        Element element = elements.get(i);
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
```

Comment: So finally, the "Kategorie" is a part of the title-Element?